# Qt deletion pointer method

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

In a Qt project I have a method

```
void ProtocolHandler::interpretData(uint8_t packet_id){
    PacketClass *packet = new RSP2StatusPacket(_packet_buf);
    emit packetReceived(packet);
}
```

where I declare an object packet of type PacketClass and then I emit the signal

```
packetReceived (PacketClass*)
```

In another class I have the following slot:

```
void ReceiverCommands::processReceivedPacket(PacketClass* pkt)
{
    status_packet *payload = pkt->getPayload();

    delete pkt
}
```

Is it correct to delete the newer PacketClass *packet in the slot method?
Sometimes my program crashes so what is the best method to delete a pointer passed in a signal/slot (I suppose I must delete the pkt because I instantiate a new packet in "interpretData" method).

Comment: you shouldn't do this, what if there are multiple slots connected to that signal (or even a double connection)

Comment: In case of PacketClass doesn't derived from QObject, I would try some approach using a wrapper class and QSharedPointer, to be sure of object deletion when all slots finish to process it . In another case, Merlin069 answer is correct.

Comment: @Jairo: What for would you need a wrapper class?

Comment: If you can guarantee, the deletopn will happen only once, then yes, this is correct (regardless of whether the class descends from QObject) and can't by itself a reason for crashes. But the approach looks code-smellish :)

Comment: @KubaOber:yes, you are right. A wrapper class isn't needed. QSharedPointer would be enough in this case. Sometimes I think that I need add extra protection to get more control, in this case, to ensure object deletion; but the smart pointer take care of it. Thanks for commenting it.

Answer (score 2):

There can be an arbitrary number of slots attached to a signal (including zero and more than one!), so you should *never* expect a slot to deallocate memory passed via a *naked* pointer.

You should be passing a `QSharedPointer<PacketClass>` and use it. It will do the deletion as and when needed.

```
typedef QSharedPointer<PacketClass> PacketClassPtr;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(PacketClassPtr)

ProtocolHandler {
    ...
    Q_SIGNAL void packetReceived(PacketClassPtr packet);
}

void ProtocolHandler::interpretData(uint8_t packet_id){
    PacketClassPtr packet(new RSP2StatusPacket(_packet_buf));
    emit packetReceived(packet);
}

void ReceiverCommands::processReceivedPacket(PacketClassPtr pkt)
{
    status_packet *payload = pkt->getPayload();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming PacketClass is derived from QObject, then call the deleteLater function: -

```
pkt->deleteLater();
```

This will handle deleting the object at the right time, after it has been through handling signals and slots and when control is returned to the event loop.

See the documentation for deleteLater [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#deleteLater), which is also relevant for Qt4

Comment: This will fail miserably if the signal is connected to slots that live in multiple threads. It's not a good suggestion. Really, you should not be using naked pointers to transfer ownership of data to slots. That's all there's to it.

Comment: You're also unclear as to *where* should the `deleteLater` be called - it'd only make sense to do it in the signal, not in the slots. At a minimum you'd need to be passing a `QPointer` so that if someone misuses this code and attaches it to a slot in a different thread, said thread won't have a dangling pointer but will be able to gracefully crash, pin-pointing the problem.

Comment: Or, at least you'd need to reimplement `connectNotify` in `ProtocolHandler` and track the connected objects to ensure that they are not in a wrong thread (or moved to a wrong thread!).

Comment: @KubaOber, all fair points, though I assumed (possibly wrongly) that this was a single threaded application. Just one point, you state that the deleteLater should be done in the signal...what do you mean by that? I though a signal didn't have a function body?